# TypeError: The response value (coroutine) is not valid

Tags: python, discord.py, quart, hypercorn

I was trying to deply my web application using `quart` and `hypercorn` but it raised:

```py
TypeError: The response value type (coroutine) is not valid
```

I don't know what happened, this is my code:

```py
# <!-- Dashboard -->
import os, quart
from hypercorn import Config; from hypercorn.asyncio import serve
from quart import Quart, redirect, render_template, url_for
from quart_discord import DiscordOAuth2Session, requires_authorization, Unauthorized
from discord.ext import ipc

dash = Quart(__name__)
config = Config()

config.bind = ["localhost:5000"]

dash.secret_key = 'smth'


dash.config['DISCORD_CLIENT_ID'] = "1067880974668533862"
dash.config['DISCORD_CLIENT_SECRET'] = "smth"
dash.config['DISCORD_REDIRECT_URI'] = "smth"
dash.config["DISCORD_BOT_TOKEN"] = "smth"

discord = DiscordOAuth2Session(dash)

# <!-- Code -->
import typing

@dash.route("/")
async def home():
    """
    Home
    """
    return render_template("index.html")

@dash.route("/login")
async def login():
    return await discord.create_session()

@dash.route("/callback")
async def callback():
    try:
        await discord.callback()
    
    except:
        return redirect(url_for("/login"))

    return redirect(url_for("/dashboard"))

@dash.route("/dashboard")
async def dashboard():
    user = await discord.fetch_user()
    return render_template("dashboard.html", user = user)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import asyncio
    asyncio.run(serve(dash, config), debug=True)
```

Any help will be apprecciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`render_template` must be awaited i.e. `return await render_template`.